# Event handler associated to DataGrid row in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, events, datagrid

I'm loading some images from a database using a PHP script through CodeIgniter, but when I try to add an event handler to do some stuff with these images, Flex compiler is showing me an error:

> 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method cloneCar.

Why I can not add an event handler in this context?

```
<mx:Accordion>
     <mx:Form id="menu5" label="Prueba" width="100%" height="100%" backgroundColor="#707070" icon="{roadIcon}">
        <mx:DataGrid x="251" y="95" dataProvider="{traffic_signals.lastResult..signal}" 
                 showHeaders="false" 
                 horizontalGridLines="false" 
                 selectionColor="#707070" 
                 themeColor="#707070" 
                 alternatingItemColors="[#707070, #707070]" 
                 borderColor="#707070" 
                 rollOverColor="#707070"> 
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="source" >
                    <mx:itemRenderer >
                        <mx:Component >
                            <mx:Image width="94" height="94" mouseDown="cloneCar(event)"/>
                        </mx:Component>
                    </mx:itemRenderer>
                </mx:DataGridColumn>
            </mx:columns>
        </mx:DataGrid>
    </mx:Form>
</mx:Accordion>
```

Without `mouseDown` sentence, everything works fine, but I need to allow drag 'n' drop (and other features) with these images.

Thanks!

EDIT:

cloneCar method defined like this:

```
private function cloneCar(e:MouseEvent):void
{
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Where have you defined your `cloneCar()` method, inside your `itemRenderer's` component or outside it? If you have defined it outside your `itemRenderer` then everything is normal, it should throw error. `ItemRenderer` is like "completely different file", so you can't access other files methods unless you inherit or make objects or have static methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem. As 'awq' said, `ItemRenderer` scope is independent of global scope, so I need to declare my event handler function as `public` and link to it in mouseDown event using `outerDocument` directive:

```
public function cloneCar(e:MouseEvent):void
{
   // do stuff
}

....

<mx:itemRenderer >
  <mx:Component >
     <mx:Image width="94" height="94" mouseDown="outerDocument.cloneCar(event)"/>
  </mx:Component>
</mx:itemRenderer>
```